# mysql select many to many that have all condition

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

just see this picture :
[image]

how to I select dorm_id(70)?

dorm_id is home ides , and facility is the propertray of theme , each home has some facility for example home id 70  has these facilities (12,13,14,17,18) , how to I select number 70 from dorm_id column .

its a search query that find dorm_id that has all facility

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make it bit clear, your requirement is not clear. Do you want `facility id` having `dorm_id` as 70.?

Comment: what do you mean by this `its only dorm that have all facility id(12,13,14,17,18)`  ??

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: your question is not complete? and please create a export from your required tables and copy and past the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements here instead of images..

Comment: I edit  the quotation just see that agin its a simple search

Comment: and see the picture too

Comment: If you're not prepared to improve the question, then please delete it.

Comment: do you see the picture ?

Comment: all I understand for your question is your need the  `dorm_id` which has all those `facility_id`. In that case all you need is `where facility_id in (12,13,14,17,18) `

Comment: no! with IN statment   select dorm_id that just has one of that I want the dorm id that have all ides @BhavikPatel

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT dorm_id FROM [table] WHERE facility_id in(SELECT id FROM facility)` to make Bhavik Patel's query automatic if you add a facility to your facility table if the table is called that way... this query should only select one record with dorm_id = 70

Comment: You have all facility 12,13,14,17,18 that mean total 5 facilitis? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem , all you need is you dont see carefully the picture !

```
SELECT dorm_id
FROM dorm
WHERE facility_id IN (12, 13, 14)
GROUP BY doctor_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ability_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way if you have your facility_id in a table called table_facility:

```
select dorm_id 
from table_dorm
group by dorm_id
having count(distinct facility_id)=(select count(distinct facility_id)
                                    from table_facility)
```

If you have them in the same table you can do it with this query:

```
select dorm_id 
from table_dorm
group by dorm_id
having count(distinct facility_id)=(select count(distinct facility_id)
                                    from table_dorm)
```

Comment: Dear sir , I just need to select drom_id for example  that  has facility_id 13 and 14 and 15 and 17 and 18 ,

Comment: I think so no more table is needed just see the picture  with eye you can find it

Comment: @kiamoz maybe the only problem it 's that you don know how to make the right question or even you don't know exactly what you need