# How to search in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, search, many-to-many

how to select doctor_id which has ability_id equal 1 and 2 and also 3?
( so the answer is 70)

I know that I cant use IN statement

```
doctor_id| ability_id
-------- | -------------
70       |      1
71       |      2
70       |      2
70       |      3
50       |      1
20       |      2
10       |      2
```

Comment: Given this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544626/mysql-select-many-to-many-that-have-all-condition, it's weird that the answer should be 70.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to Gordon's query would be to aggregate by doctor, restrict to abilities in 1, 2, or 3, and then retain those doctors having three distinct abilities.  This would imply that a retained doctor has all three abiliites.

```
SELECT doctor_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE ability_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY doctor_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ability_id) = 3
```

Comment: it's correct but  if I changed the last line to  COUNT(*) = 3 that works too , why should  I use distinct  here ,

Comment: @faezehrasouli If a given doctor could have more than one record for a given ability, then using `COUNT(*)` would give a false positive.  E.g. if the doctor had 1, 1, 2 then `COUNT(*)` would report 3, which is wrong.

Comment: You might be OK with just `COUNT(*)` if you are certain that an ability can only ever appear once for a given doctor, but using `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` is always correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select doctor_id
from t
group by doctor_id
having sum(ability_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(ability_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(ability_id = 3) > 0 ;
```

The "not use `in`" is a very strange requirement.  A more natural way to write this is:

```
select doctor_id
from t
where ability_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by doctor_id
having count(*) = 3;
```